# I want to install Windows 10 alongside my Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, windows

I have an issue where i want to install WIndows 10 alongside Ubuntu 18.04 LTS because i can't play most of my games such as Roblox. If i do so, Windows will eat the GRUB bootloader and i will have to re-nstall Ubuntu but i don't want so. I don't want to do VirtualBox either due to the graphic card drivers and VIrtualBx lags my PC. Anyone know a trick?

Thanks.

Comment: I was same as you a few weeks ago.  Made sure I had ubuntu iso on a extra usb stick, and installed windows.  Was quite happy when I went to reboot  and just had to click on ubuntu.  Not like the bad old days.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how modern your PC is, Ubuntu should usually be bootable via the UEFI boot menu. Using that you can circumvent/avoid the Windows boot loader and boot Linux. From there you should be able to install `grub` again.

Comment: Actually, if UEFI and Ubuntu already installed in that mode (as it should be), then there's no need to reinstall Grub and the order for the OSes installation is irrelevant. After installing Windows, if needed, users just have to change the bootloader back to to Ubuntu in UEFI boot settings and then run `sudo update-grub` to have the new Windows added to the menu.